# How to use ES6 classes in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, es6-class

I want to use ES6 classes in my test on protractor. But when i run `protractor conf.js` i have `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` on this line

```
export default class AngularHomePage {
```

Also i can't use await/async for some reason, besides `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` setting.

Can i use this syntax at all, or am i missing something?

I tried to import this class as `import AngularHomePage from './PageObject'`, but it's give me same SyntaxError, but for this line. Then i use `const homePage = require('../Protractor demo/PageObject')`, but it not work either.

This is my class code:

```
export default class AngularJsHomePage {
    constructor() {
        this.nameInput = element(by.model('yourName'))
        this.greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'))
    }

    async get () {
        await browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org')
    }

    async setName (name) {
        await this.nameInput.sendKeys(name)
    }

    async getGreetingText () {
        return await this.greeting.getText()
    }

    getGreeting () {
        return this.greeting
    }
}
```

This is my spec.js code

```
// import { element, by, browser } from "protractor"
// import AngularJsHomePage from "./PageObject"
const homePage = require('../Protractor demo/PageObject')

describe('Angular homepage', function() {
    it('should greet the named user', function() {
        const page = new homePage()

        await page.get()

        await page.setName('Julie')

        expect(await page.getGreetingText()).toEqual('Hello Julie')
    })
})
```

Comment: add `"target": "es6",` in your `tscongif.json`

Comment: But i am using JavaScript and don't have tsconfig.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use npm called **babel**.
It is used to convert ECMAScript 2015 and newer versions of JS into backward versions.

1. `npm install babel-register`
2. `npm install babel-preset-env`
3. In your protractor.conf.js file:

```js
onPrepare: () => {
    require("babel-register");
}
```

4. Create in your main project folder a file called **.babelrc**

```js
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

**You can read more about Babel [here](https://babeljs.io/).**
Maybe you'll need to install some more babel packages, depending on the versions you're working with.

Comment: Do i need install something else? Because i have this error ->

Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

Comment: install *babel-preset-env* npm as well

Comment: That not help either

But, i read through Babel docs and managed to find a solution, not sure most efficient one. I install this packages
`@babel/core (as save-dev)
@bablel/register (as save-dev)
@bable/polyfill (as save)
@babel/runtime (as save)
@babel/plugin-transform-runtime (as save-dev)`
And .babelrc
`{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    ]
}`

So thanks for help finding babel!